# Finding the Radius of the Appropriate Tube Fitting a Prism

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The question is the following:

> Schuyler has made some glass prisms to be sold as window decorations. Each prism is four inches tall, and has a regular hexagonal base with half-inch sides. They are to be shipped in cylindrical tubes that are 4 inches tall. What radius should Schuyler use for the tubes? Once a prism is inserted into its tube, what volume remains for packing material?

To find the area of the prism, I did:
$$12(0.5\cdot(0.25 cos30))$$

To find the radius of the cylindrical tube, I did:
$$4\cdot \pi r^2 \le 12(0.5\cdot(0.25 cos30)) $$
$$r \approx 0.322"$$

But the radius that I got is wrong, because after I tested out to see the remaining volume by doing $\pi(0.322)^2 - 12(0.5\cdot(0.25 cos30))$, I constantly get a negative answer.

What part of my approach my doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular hexagon fits snugly into a circle with radius equal to a side, so the tube should have a half inch radius.  To get the volume left for packing, you need to subtract the area of the hexagon from the area of the circle, then multiply by four inches.